# Technology for video encoding and decoding on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, video-editing

I want to know  answers for the below questions as I'm totally confused with what to do and how to do.

I thought of developing one video editor application for Windows Phone 8. But I couldn't find out the proper API that supports doing this.

On browsing and on seeing the Microsoft website I came to know that DirectShow is completely not used in Windows Phone 8. If so, the only alternative is Media Foundation. Does media foundation support video editing, which includes encoding and decoding, on Windows Phone 8? I specifically need it to support Windows Phone 8. Do any links exist out there regarding this? If Media Foundation also doesn't support Windows Phone 8, what is the alternative for video editing in Windows Phone 8? I'm trying to use the metro UI.

Comment: Maybe you find some supported methods in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media Namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Foundation support is [limited to playback functions on Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681688%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). For video editing you're pretty much limited to what you can do in .NET and standard C/C++ (i.e. code the codecs yourself or use 3rd party libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I also need the video frames on Windows Phone 8 for some research stuff (not video editor). Have you already looked at the "TransferVideoFrame" method in the Media Foundation framework? I am still trying to understand how this works but according to the documentation this method should do the trick.