# Compressing frames inside an AVI video

Tags: c#, video, compression, windows-phone, avi

I've built a Windows Phone class to convert some WriteableBitmap into a AVI Full Frame (Uncompressed). Videos are really huge. Is there a simple codec implementation existing, like a codec that just zip images, or something that is making a next/previous XOR then zip it in jpeg?

Windows Phone doesn't allow any unsafe code and most DLL cannot be wrapped into a C# WP library. So that's why I'm coding something from scratch. Note that I'm more efficient at coding from scratch than in studying C++ existing sources (I'm not a C++ coder), so what I'm searching is infos about a compressed AVI format that can be achieved without writing 100000 lines. I've used AVI because the specs are simple.

[EDIT]

I've found something very interesting [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5834/A-C-MPEG1-Image-Compression-Class) on codeproject, from a 2004 article. It's a 100% C# source to convert frames to mpeg-1. Sadly that's i frame, and not p frame, so files are 3 times larger than an expected mpeg-1 average file size.

[EDIT]

To describe more my project, what I'll do is to apply some effects on a captured movie. This movie will then be uploaded on Youtube or some other websites. Thus, the user expect the exact resolution used on the phone, at least 25 frames/s, a decent quality, and a short upload time. So I can't stop with a Mpeg-1 I-Frames. I'll need to study about prediction in mpeg-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take this to be a continuation/re-post of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905826/easiest-well-known-video-compression-codec-that-can-be-coded-from-scratch) (but with a few more details). As I mentioned in the comments of that post, there is a whole universe of video codecs out there. One reason for the proliferation is that a lot of people like to re-invent wheels. However, a more salient reason is that there are a lot of different use cases for video.

You seem to be asking for a lot, yet there are a lot of variables you have not presented:

- You express a need for a video encoder that will run purely in software on a Windows Phone device, which is necessarily a fairly low-powered machine; do you need it to run in real-time? I.e., do you expect a frame of video to be compressed almost immediately after to send in the uncompressed frame (within a few milliseconds)? Or can you let the device think about the compression for awhile?
- How large are the video frames? Are you doing screen capture on a WP device, i.e., computer-generated data? Or are you reading raw frames from the camera and hoping to compress those?
- Following from the previous point, what type of video data? Computer-generated data will look better with a certain class of codecs. Photo-quality images (from camera) implies a different family of codecs.
- What bitrate are you aiming for? If you have 1 second of video, what's the max amount of bytes it should occupy (or so you hope)?
- Who is the eventual consumer of the video? In the last post, you indicated you wanted to upload to YouTube. If that's the case, you're in luck, since YouTube -- backed by FFmpeg -- handles nearly every codec in the universe, so you would have a lot of options.

I don't know much about Windows Phone programming. However, any WP device is going to technically have hardware video encoding capabilities. I've done some cursory Googling to determine if you get any access to that at the application programming level but I can't find any evidence that it's possible (and [this SO answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936531/video-encoding-and-decoding-in-windows-phone-8) that the functionality is not there).

I hope to impress upon you that writing a video encoder is a **LOT** of work (look at my username; I know from whence I speak). Generally, they require quite a lot of CPU horsepower (and, consequently, battery power, especially when implemented in pure software). However, you have already made some guesses about a codec that uses standard zlib. In fact, there are a few video codecs based on straight zlib, namely MSZH and ZLIB, collectively the [Lossless Codec Libraries](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Lossless_Codec_Libraries). That wiki page has a basic bitstream description (disclosure: I operate that wiki site). I'm confident the WP libraries include access to zlib encoding, so this might be a starting point, and YouTube should be able to digest the resulting files.

There is also a video codec that combines XOR and zlib as you guessed ([Dosbox Capture Codec](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=DosBox_Capture_Codec)), but it's probably not appropriate for your application.

Do the libraries provide access to standard JPEG (i.e., can it encode JPEG files)? Another option (depending on the video type) would be successive frames of still JPEG images stuffed in the AVI file. This is known as Motion JPEG or MJPEG. However, it's roughly equivalent in bitrate to intra-only MPEG-1, which you expressed as being inadequate.

I hope I have given you some ideas and useful avenues to pursue on your path to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for this very complete and intelligent answer! I've refined my goal so that compatibility with WP is not a requirement anymore. WP uses a limited set of compatible codecs, so that a project that would require compatibility on both sides would be really complicated to achieve. I now only aim being compatible with a site like Youtube. I updated my question. I'll read it more today so I can find some avenues that will lead me to a format that I can easily code in C# in some days without a deep understanding of C++.

Comment: Is it an option to compile a C code base and call into it using a native code interface facility? There are a few well known and well used libraries including libtheora and libvpx that might do the job. Again, they could be computationally expensive. Generally, more advanced codecs and more efficient bitrates require more CPU time to encode.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I fail. I've no problem to find existent sources, but I'm just not good in C/C++ to call or compile anything. I can understand algorithms, though. Anyway. I see on Sourceforge that libtheoraplayer has been adapted to Windows Phone too, but haven't found any encoder projects yet. And my searches are covering mpeg1,2,4,h264,theora. Even WMV, which is a Microsoft thing. The simple C# mpeg-1 class I'veported to WP is something totally alone in its kind. I'll continue to read about prediction in mpeg-1, http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/cml/dsp/training/coding/mpeg1/