# Any way to decrease byte size of recorded video in Win phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, compression

In my app user can record video and there is an api in which I have to request upload video. I am using httpclient for it but it is not working for file size greater than 25 MB.

So Can anyone tell me how to decrease quality or anything by which no of bytes will decrease. I have limited the video recording to 1 min.

Comment: Did you try using the third party Codecs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975328/compressing-frames-inside-an-avi-video?lq=1

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do that and the link provided contains no implementation.